How to exclude a collection from affecting another collections LineArt individual silhouette?
I have multiple collections, each with their own LineArt applied, each with a different style. One collection it for the main objects, the other for small details that are "drawn over" the other one.
The screenshots below show all LineArt modifiers, the yellow ones are for the main collection, the cyan for the detail collection.

The problem seems to come from the Individual Silhouette on the main collection: since the details are in front, they seem to affect the silhouette.

Is there a way to ignore the occlusion from other collections, preferably without multiple separate renders?
My .blend file:


Edit:
The problem is, that I have multiple sets of LineArt on multiple grease pencil objects, all applying to different collections, so I can have more styles. The building has the blue-white lines, but some details on the building are separate models.
The first image is only the building, the second is only the details, the third is both.

I did kind of find a solution, which is deactivating the detail collection, baking all LineArt modifiers separately besides the detail one, then baking the detail LineArt. But this is quite cumbersome.
Another possibility could be adding more view layers, so the details are separated and can be then added in compositing, but this doesn't work live.
Better solutions would still be appreciated.
This is what I'm trying to achieve:


I am a little confused about what it is that you are trying to accomplish. In particular, your words, Is there a way to ignore the occlusion from other collections? is too vague for me. Which set of lines/line art modifier are you addressing? The white lines? If you don't want the rest of your line art modifiers blocking/occluding the white lines then, you can simply move the lineart modifier that generates your white lines to the bottom of your list of modifiers. That way, they show up on top when rendered.
